Dealing with High Voltage Low Current Transformer Inrush and bypassing a Thermistor
As a learning project, I am designing a power supply section of a guitar amplifier that uses a 120V Primary, 250V 45mA 40VA Secondary Transformer. Without any thermistor in-line on the main supply, I'm getting around 1A of inrush on the rectifier diodes in Kicads ngspice simulation which settles to a <40mA mean load.

My intial thought was to stick a ~100-150 NTC thermistor before the primary which would limit the Inrush peak to 50mA and and reach a .5 factor at around 50C. At this point, the thermistor would be around 75R with the reservoir charged up to ~24V and 3mA at the diodes. An LR8 linear reg (13-450V in, Vout < Vin-12) would feed a 12V coil and wait for the reservoir to reach at least 24V to close the solid state relay and bypass the NTC thermistor.

I'm new to learning EE and there are clearly some major flaws with this thinking. While it would be cool if these could go from 150R-.1R that just isn't reality, and I'm still making a sudden jump from 25V to 250. I need to tape Ohms Law to the top of my monitor heh.
I've tried increasing R1(2.2K) directly after the rectifier to drop the voltage to ~200V but would require an unrealistically large resistor and ton of wasted energy.

Is there some obvious solution to limit this inrush using transistors or just some other solution that I am missing? Don't have much experience with them yet but when I looked into power mosfets rated at 120V they have limited range of resistance and a PTC so I can't use them in place of the relay/therm. Pretty stumped here, and would love to reference a linear power supply project with a similar high voltage, low current transformer situation if anyone happens to have a link! Thanks!

limited range of resistance naturally, but I think it wide enough for an ever increasing range of needs and purposes. You could explain why not go with a contemporary PS design: switched.

My gateway into learning more about electronics has been guitar tube amps, and the schematics everyone shares and talks about are from older amps that use a power and push/pull output transformer. I definitely don't have have anything against switched supplies, just not much shared in the hobbist space about feeding tube anodes with 200+ volts while also supplying the heater filaments 1A 6.3V by using high frequency DC-DC transformers. Just picked up the hobby so its a bit intimidating messing with high frequencies with no experience, especially if I eventually want to print a PCB

How much inrush are you concerned about, and why? (Normally inrush is a concern when it's more than 50A -- at the mains input!)

(The diagram shows 220 Ω for R1, the text states 2.2 kΩ.)

@TimWilliams I may be confused on transformer ratings. I was multplying my inrush peak on the secondaries ~1A by Voltage(250) and coming up with around 250W thinking I had to have it close to the 40VA rating on the transformer, is loading the secondaries by a factor of x10-20 the RMS for .1-.2 seconds on startup a non-issue?

Yes, it's a non-issue. The transformer power ratings (as for most other components) are for continuous use, not the fractions of a second it takes to switch on your circuit.

Sticking with a "mains frequency power supply", you could transform the series resistor before the reservoir capacitor to the primary side.
This may result in a value suitable for the NTC:
Just drop both R1 and the shunt.

Don't worry about the transformer. It's just a lump of iron and copper!
A transformer can handle overload conditions for some seconds before internal temperatures begin to rise dangerously.  More than enough time for a suitably rated fuse to act.
For durations less than that, such as for inrush (assuming modestly sized capacitors, as is the case here), it's just fine with.
Limiting values are continuous duty only.  Use it at up to 40VA, averaged over long periods (hours), avoid long overloads (say, seconds above 80VA?), and you're fine.
Using it above nameplate ratings, will cause more temp rise, and at least a reduction in lifetime (higher temp = faster insulation degradation), but also a cascade failure pattern: temp rise --> higher Cu resistance --> hotspots form --> insulation breakdown accelerates --> insulation carbonizes, drawing current between turns --> turns melt and short out --> etc.  The lifetime reduction might be, say, from decades of continuous operation at or below ratings, down to some years at, say, 20-50% above ratings, or maybe some hours at +100%, etc.  Obviously, the precise failure statistics depend on construction, materials, voltage, etc., and these values should not be taken as reference; just for sake of discussion.
(Also, failure is greatly accelerated at elevated voltage, due to magnetic saturation drawing much higher primary/magnetizing current, plus further increased core losses.  Thus, the most predictable case for over-rating is simply running at higher current.)
So, we choose ratings that deliver reasonable performance (regulation, losses) with adequate lifetime.  There is nothing fundamental about a transformer that determines its VA rating; it's just an engineering tradeoff.
Notice that a cap-input rectifier has a typical power factor of 0.5 or so, so you only get 20W output for that 40VA capacity.  This may be rolled into the component rating (as I recall, Hammond Mfg. for example rates their tube transformers by DC output in this condition?), or left to you to calculate.  This makes sense, as you gain ~1.4x voltage in the rectifier, but the price is you lose more than the inverse in current capacity -- no free lunch.  (You can see this in the simulation by measuring RMS input current (times Vrms --> apparent power) and comparing to output power (Vdc * Idc is always real power).)
